# How to express negative infinity in XAML?

Tags: xaml

I can set the property value to positive infinity by just writing `Property="Infinity"`, but when I try setting it to negative infinity by writing `Property="-Infinity"` or  `Property="NegativeInfinity"` I get the error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

How to express negative infinity in XAML?

Comment: -Infinity should work... is it possible your Property is unsigned? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002.aspx

Comment: The property definitely supports negative values and `Infinity`, but not `-Infinity`. Examples are the `Canvas.Left` and `Margin` properties. The information in your link corresponds to XAML2009 which is sadly unsupported by WPF/Silverlight/WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

I know, almost 5 years later, but...

You could do something like:

```
Minimum="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:Decimal.MinValue}}"
<!--sys is the System alias-->
```

You can access a `const` that is recognized as the minimum value for that type by a simple binding.